# Programming language to choose to execute bash commands

Tags: c++, linux, bash, output

For my school project I must make a C++ program. The program has to use already installed applications on the Linux OS. To get familiar with managing other processes from within a C++ application I want to make a program that sets a wlan interface to monitor mode. The code that I have written so far is pretty long and doesn't seems efficient. Are there any ways to make my code more compact and efficient? At the end of the program I want to execute iwconfig to check if the wlan really is in monitor mode. What is the best way to do that?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string wlan = "wlan1";
    pid_t ifconfigDown;
    ifconfigDown = fork();
    if(ifconfigDown == 0)//ifconfig
    {
        execl("/sbin/ifconfig", "ifconfig", wlan.c_str(), "down",(char*)0 );
    }
    else //parent
    {
        usleep(500000);
        pid_t iwconfigMode;
        iwconfigMode = fork();
        if(iwconfigMode == 0)//ifconfig
        {
            execl("/sbin/iwconfig","iwconfig",wlan.c_str(),"mode","monitor",(char*)0 );
        }
        else//parent
        {
            usleep(500000);
            pid_t ifconfigUp;
            ifconfigUp = fork();
            if(ifconfigUp == 0)//ifconfig
            {
                execl("/sbin/ifconfig", "ifconfig", wlan.c_str(), "up", (char*)0 );
            }
            else//parent
            {
                usleep(500000);
                pid_t iwconfig;
                iwconfig = fork();
                if(iwconfig == 0)//iwconfig
                {
                    execl("/sbin/iwconfig", "iwconfig", (char*)0 );
                    //check if wlan1 is in monitor mode
                }
            }
        }
        waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);
        return 0;
    }
}


    string rPopenEnd (string cmd)
    {
         FILE *fp = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
        if (fp == NULL)
        {
            return "ERROR";
        }
        else
        {
            uint16_t line_size = 20;
            char line[line_size];
            string result;
            while (fgets(line, line_size, fp))
                 result += line;

            wait(NULL);
            return result;
        }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    rPopenEnd("iwconfig");
}
```

Comment: Instead of sleeping for some amount of time, just call [`wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) to wait for the child process to finish. And for the last command, you could use [`popen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) instead so you're able to read the output from the command.

Comment: For other purposes than to get used to launch programs from `C/C++` I don't think it's a good idea to use `C/C++` in this case.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Wait is indeed a better option. I have implemented that now. The problem with popen is that outputs data directly to the console. I don't want that. Can this be fixed?

Comment: @skyking Quite possible. I have been having much trouble. What program language would be good for my requirements. After the putting in monitor mode of the wlan interface I want to execute commands with streaming output such as top. That would make it even more complex to read and write to the program.

Comment: If you use `popen` with the `"r"` mode, it should pipe all standard output of the child-process to your parent process.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes it does. But it also prints to output directly to the console. I don't want to demolish the user experience by littering the output shown by the console.

Comment: That is should not do, then you're doing something wrong. Or `iwconfig` writes to `stderr` as well if it notices that `stdout` is not a terminal, or something similar?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have added the code that I have written for popen(). What should I do?

Comment: Two problems: You should not `wait` for that child process, and secondly you should call `pclose` to close the `FILE` pointer. Other than that I see no problem on your end (well, maybe the line size is a little short, could be longer). Have you tried piping the output of `iwconfig` in a terminal to see what happens? E.g. `iwconfig > foo` or `iwconfig | less`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg piping to less gives me the same output as without less. I have also closed the FILE. It doesn't help. The printed output with popen() is by the way partially displayed. It is a part of the output that I would normally get when typing iwconfig in a console.

Comment: @RikSmits I'd say that a basic shell script would be a good candidate. Since you seem to rely on programs that are traditionally only there in a POSIX system it's a good chance that you're relying on POSIX compliance and then a POSIX compatible shell is available (it could even be just `bash`).